# elasticsearch match_all query not returning everything

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index that has 400 items. But when I make a basic "match_all" query, I only get back 396 items. It's not a size issue.

I've looked at the items in question, and I can't see pinpoint any issue with them. Could it be a mapping issue?

Does anyone know what could be the cause? I haven't encountered this type of issue before.

```
POST /_search
 {
  "from" : 0, "size" : 500,
  "query" : {
      "match_all":{}
   }
 }
```

The only think I can think of that is different in this index is that there are variable fields. It isn't always a set list of fields like most other indices I use.

Comment: How do you know you have 400 docs?

Comment: @khachik hi, when I visit the http://<endpoint>/<index>/_search?size=500, I can see all it says 400 items, but when I make a Postman query, I only get back 396.

Comment: Try `http://<endpoint>/<index>/_count` and post the result

Comment: `{
count: 400,
_shards: {
total: 5,
successful: 5,
skipped: 0,
failed: 0
}
}`

Comment: Remove `"from" : 0,` and try